# good clean interface library to complement jquery.js and backbone.js?

Tags: jquery, frameworks, backbone.js, instant-messaging

***I plan to build a facebook instant messenger clone,  and look for a jquery interface framework 
what I aim to so is:***

http://www.arrowchat.com/demo.branded/

Now the idea is to have a clean user interface library to handle the dialogs and other stuff..
I already looked at:

- ember to complicated pre-mature for now
- backbone but does not support ui stuff
- jquery-ui distaste on this one not sure why, its to bloated for starters
- http://www.jeasyui.com/demo/index.php seems nice but not very tied to backbone.js - this is perfect but need lib thats more dedicated to backbone.js

Are there any other jquery library's to render user interfaces perhaps specific to backbone.js to get a decent layout up and running on clean code? thx!

Comment: It's unlikely you're going to find something as specific as you are looking for.  jQuery user interface libraries tend to want to be generic for use in any kind of situation.  I don't get what you mean when you say jQueryUI is bloated.  It's not, in fact it's broken up so that you only have to include the parts you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at either [Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) or [Foundation Zurb](http://foundation.zurb.com).

They both give you a responsive scaffolding with common UI elements. If you want more JS plugins then Bootstrap would be the one.